# Using lapply with colorRampPalette

Tags: r, heatmap

I have the following vector:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
```

What I want to do is to assign color for each number using `colorRampPalette`.
But why this command gives more output than I expected:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
mycolorfunction <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Set1"))
unlist(lapply(as.list(x),mycolorfunction))
```

It gives this:

```
 [1] "#E41A1C" "#E41A1C" "#E41A1C" "#E41A1C" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#999999"
[12] "#E41A1C" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#FF7F00" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#FF7F00"
[23] "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#FF7F00" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#7E6E85" "#E1C62F" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#4DAF4A" "#FF7F00"
[34] "#A65628" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#4DAF4A" "#FF7F00" "#A65628" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#4DAF4A" "#FF7F00" "#A65628"
[45] "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#4DAF4A" "#FF7F00" "#A65628" "#999999" "#E41A1C" "#4DAF4A" "#FF7F00" "#A65628" "#999999"
[56] "#E41A1C" "#4DAF4A" "#FF7F00" "#A65628" "#999999"
```

I expect it to produce vector of size 20 with only 5 color Hex.
What's the right way to do it?

At the end of the day I'd like to use the final vector as `RowSideColors` argument in `heatmap.2`.

Comment: Try this: `mycolorfunction(5)[x]`. Or using `max`: `mycolorfunction(max(x))[x]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly use you function `mycolorfunction` and `x` as a vector of indices:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
library(RColorBrewer)
mycolorfunction <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Set1"))

mycolorfunction(max(x))[x]
#  [1] "#E41A1C" "#E41A1C" "#E41A1C" "#4DAF4A" "#4DAF4A" "#4DAF4A" 
#  [7] "#4DAF4A" "#4DAF4A" "#4DAF4A" "#4DAF4A" "#FF7F00" "#FF7F00"
# [13] "#FF7F00" "#A65628" "#999999" "#999999" "#999999" "#999999"
# [19] "#999999" "#999999"
```